# Quartz mineral category

Tags: geology, mineralogy

Different learning resources categorise quartz differently. Strictly speaking, is quartz a silicate mineral or an oxide mineral?

Answer (score 4):

Quartz is a silicate at the most used Dana and Strunz classifications of minerals.

Several [websites](http://webmineral.com/data/Quartz.shtml#.YEJ8Y-CCEzQ) and mineralogists classify it as silicate.

The structure of quartz is similar to other silicates with Si-O tetrahedres.

[image]

Quartz structure. [quartzpage.de](http://www.quartzpage.de/gen_struct.html)

Answer (score 3):

> quartz a silicate mineral or an oxide mineral

Both. The two are not mutually exclusive.

Quartz is an oxide, because it is an oxide of the element silicon.

Quartz is also a silicate, because it is composed of a framework of silicate tetrahedra.